# apply from from local gradle cause sync failed in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I was going to extract some common functions from the `build.gradle` into a `helper.gradle` via:

```
apply from: 'helper.gradle'
```

The script was perfect while I launch it from command line such as

```
gradle assembleFlavorDebug
```

However, when I go back to the Android Studio (version 15, built on Nov 25, 2015) and click the `Sync Project with Gradle Files` it failed with the error:

```
Cause: error=2, No such file or directory
```

and the error locates the line where `apply from:` is.

I also tried to change the path in `apply from:` from relative to absolute one but it didn't work neither.

What should I do to make the `Sync` function work in Android Studio with the `apply from:` in my gradle script?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. The reason was the 'helper.gradle' was going to invoke the `android` command however the `PATH` environment in the GUI application, the Android Studio, is different from the one in terminal.